# Facebook API - How to get the access token?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to get the access token following [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)

First, I have to redirect user to the Facebook login page. The response looks like:

```
http://localhost/?code=AQDcY0NnkyHy2ixcmn8CR2W3F21DvXFwcyP4NgvalTIan4pCC19uInXLKNPr48FkL2VKPbY2OL98zw5XrD7lbrZ_rnT0zDs4Rumc1QOLAfD0r3Ekpac9tKmBMEImIawOm8yxmR92IL1
```

Fine, we can finally exchange code for an Acess Token

```
if(empty($_GET['code'])){
  header("Location :https://www.facebook.com/v5.0/dialog/oauth?
  client_id={app-id}
  &redirect_uri={"h t t p s:// www.domain.com/login"}
  &state={"{st=state123abc,ds=123456789});
}
else{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/oauth/access_token?
   client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
   &client_secret={app-secret}
   &code=$_GET['code']');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
}
```

And here I've received suprise:

```
string(0) ""
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your file in root of localhost `www` or in a folder in `www` ?

Comment: I'm using xampp. My file is in /htdocs directly

Comment: Did you create a test account on facebook developpers to work on localhost ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/ clearing that in your question will  get you right answers.

Comment: Yes, I've done this

Comment: Responsecode is 302 - redirection to "unsupported browser". I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Looks into  redirection method `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}` check link in you question

Comment: give me a litle time will write something

Comment: What is wrong with that redirection? I don't want to public my app-id on stackoverflow

Comment: its not public you need to redirect your users so facebookknows they are from your app

Comment: This redirect `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}` gives me correct response: localhost?code=somecodehere

Comment: It is about exchanging code for access token.

Comment: you dont need an answer then you got it :)

Comment: No, look. I want to exchange code for an access token. Here is the main problem

Comment: It returns me `"string(0) ""`, status code 302, redirection because of "unsupported browser".

Comment: Why not use the official Facebook PHP SDK?

Comment: The code you have shown above contains syntax errors, making it hard to tell if you were just inattentive while posting the problem description, or if you actually made mistakes in your code there.

Answer (score 0):

This what I used on one my project read comments in it.

`constant` (define) can be changed to example `url = "url";`

```
//The username or email address of the account.
define('USERNAME', 'myusername');

//The password of the account.
define('PASSWORD', 'mypassword');

//Set a user agent. This basically tells the server that we are using Chrome ;)
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');

//Where our cookie information will be stored (needed for authentication).
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');

//URL of the login form.
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'http://example.com/login.php');

//Login action URL. Sometimes, this is the same URL as the login form.
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'http://example.com/login-check.php');


//An associative array that represents the required form fields.
//You will need to change the keys / index names to match the name of the form
//fields.
$postValues = array(
    'username' => USERNAME,
    'password' => PASSWORD
);

//Initiate cURL.
$curl = curl_init();

//Set the URL that we want to send our POST request to. In this
//case, it's the action URL of the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);

//Tell cURL that we want to carry out a POST request.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//Set our post fields / date (from the array above).
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));

//We don't want any HTTPS errors.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Where our cookie details are saved. This is typically required
//for authentication, as the session ID is usually saved in the cookie file.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

//Sets the user agent. Some websites will attempt to block bot user agents.
//Hence the reason I gave it a Chrome user agent.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

//Tells cURL to return the output once the request has been executed.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Allows us to set the referer header. In this particular case, we are 
//fooling the server into thinking that we were referred by the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);

//Do we want to follow any redirects?
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

//Execute the login request.
curl_exec($curl);

//Check for errors!
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

//We should be logged in by now. Let's attempt to access a password protected page
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/protected-page.php');

//Use the same cookie file.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

//Use the same user agent, just in case it is used by the server for session validation.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

//We don't want any HTTPS / SSL errors.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Execute the GET request and print out the result.
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

> now we come to your question

**There are several ways to get access tokens, To generate an app access token, you need**:

1. Your App ID
2. Your App Secret

One of solution :

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
  ?client_id={your-app-id}
  &client_secret={your-app-secret}
  &grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Get url by token:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{your-user-id}/accounts?access_token={user-access-token}
```

See more here on facebook documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

**Finall Word! you need to specify your `app_id` or `user_id` in url as I know**